# conda env running conda command /usr/bin/env bash no file

Tags: bash, environment-variables, conda

I run git bash in window, and create a `conda` environment:

```
conda create -n test python=2.7  
source activate test
```

Inside the environment, I use the command:

```
conda install
```

It returns error message, `/usr/bin/env bash no file or directory`.  Why?

I don't have a problem running `conda` outside the environment.

Comment: Check that I've edited your question accurately enough.  What damage did the `source activate test` command do to your environment?  Have you compared the environment before and after?  Maybe try: `env > before.env; source activate test; env > after.env; diff before.env after.env` — do the differences explain the problem?  If the `env > after.env` fails, the `diff` probably will too, but those failures are symptomatic of problems with `activate`.

Comment: It's because the env folder in git bash isn't in /usr/bin. I haven't tested it, but usually when I run python scripts in git bash I use /usr/bin/bash as my shebang

Comment: thanks, this is my first time post, I will check on that..